# Android books on the operating system

Tags: android, operating-system

I know that there are many books out there for Android developers, but I need some books for the operating system itself. So can anyone help me, I know that it is Linux based, but I need something more on it.
Thanks in advance

Comment: So I'm interested in the memory management, input/output, file systems, processes and so on.

Answer (score 6):

There are no books on the operating system internals available at the present time, based on my most recent survey of the space. A couple should be published in the next few months:

- "Embedded Android" from O'Reilly is listed as being due out 22 May
- "XDA's Android Hacker's Toolkit" from Wiley is listed as being due out in 13 June